# Assign object to "this"

Tags: javascript

Say I have a class and some static helper methods like this:

```
function MyClass (myVar) {
    this.myVar = myVar;

    this.replaceMe = function (value) {
        // this will fail
        this = MyClass.staticHelper( value );

        return this;
    }

    this.revealVar = function () {
        alert( this.myVar );
    }
}

MyClass.staticHelper = function (instance, value) {
    return new MyClass( instance.myVar + value );
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
var instance = new MyClass( 2 );

instance.revealVar(); // alerts 2
instance.replaceMe( 40 ).revealVar(); // alerts 42
```

The reason is that my class has a slightly more complicated structure and I don't want to assign all internal variables manually everytime, but rather replace the entire object. Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Looks like you just want `return MyClass.staticHelper(this, value );`. You cannot replace `this`, but you can return a new, similar object.

Comment: This will only return the new object within a call chain, but not actually replace the instance.

Comment: Yes, that's not possible. You can create a wrapper for the whole class and keep an internal reference to the actual instance though.

Comment: Awe, rats. Would've been nice. I'll just change my design and not overwrite the object but return them to enable call chains. For actual overwriting I can still either reassign the variable or use static functions I have for that. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to "replace" the object by making the current reference a different object, you will need to change all its properties. You can't assign to anything outside of your scope chain.

Answer (score 2):

> `instance.replaceMe( 40 ).revealVar();` alerts 42

OK, for that `return MyClass.staticHelper(this, value);` would suffice. The question is only whether the next call to `instance.revealVar()` should now alert 2 or 42 - if you want `instance` to be changed to 42 it gets more complicated:

```
this = MyClass.staticHelper( value ); // this will fail
```

…because [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is not a common variable, but a *keyword* and [*evaluates to the value of the ThisBinding of the current execution context*](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.1) which [is set depending on how the function is entered](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3) - you cannot assign to it, you can only set it when invoking the function.

> I don't want to assign all internal variables manually everytime, but rather replace the entire object.

Unfortunately you have to do so, without changing the properties of `instance` object (and the closure-hidden variables) you won't change the `instance` and `revealVar()` will stay 2.

> Is there a simple way to do so?

Yes, it can be done programmatically. The simplest method would be to [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the constructor (again) *on* the current instance, like it happens when invoked with the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
MyClass.call( instance, instance.myVar + value );
```

Yet you can't use this like the static function which creates a completely new instance. Either you put it in a static method and call that from `replaceMe` with `this`, or you just put it directly in `replaceMe`.

If you need a static method that at first returns a completely new instance, you could use that as well by copying the new properties on the old instance:

```
….replaceMe = function(val) {
    var newInst = MyClass.staticHelper(this, val); // new MyClass(this.myVar+val);
    for (var prop in newInst)
        if (newInst.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            this[prop] = newInst[prop];
    return this;
};
```

That means overwriting the old attributes, and also the old closures can be garbage-collected now as nothing refers to them any more.

Btw, I'd recommend to [put your methods on the prototype instead of assigning them in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

How about just returning the new instance:

```
function MyClass(myVar) {
    // ...

    this.replaceMe = function (value) {
        return MyClass.staticHelper(this, value);
    }

    // ...
}

MyClass.staticHelper = function (instance, value) {
    return new MyClass( instance.myVar += value );
}
```

Comment: As mentioned on the comments of the question, this won't actually replace the instance, i.e. outside of a call chain the object will be untouched.

Comment: @IngoBürk I also added `+=` instead of `=` so that will mutate the object property.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. But that defeats the purpose of my question: My class needs an update on several variables upon a change. I was looking for a way not to have to do that manually.

Comment: @IngoBürk Well you can't change `this` as it is a constant object. I think you could use the module pattern for this. I'll update shortly.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that now. I just thought maybe there's a way, after all Javascript is a language with a lot of "features". :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why this is not going to work in Javascript.

First, despite that it looks like a variable, `this` is actually a function call* and therefore cannot be assigned to. `this=foo` is the same as `bar()=baz`. So it's not possible to have code like this:

```
a = 5
a.change(10)
alert(a == 10) // nope
```

Second, even if `this=z` were possible, that approach would fail anyways, because Javascript passes by value, therefore it's not possible to have a function that changes the value of its argument:

```
a = 5
change(a)
alert(a == 10) // nope
```

`*` "is" means "fully identical in every way"

Comment: The specification does not say that it is a function call. [It only mentionds `ThisBinding`](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3) which is described as *"The value associated with the `this` keyword within ECMAScript code associated with this execution context."* (http://es5.github.com/#x10.3, http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.1).

Comment: The `this` pointer inside a function is a read-only value, not a function call. That's the reason assignments to `this` do not work.

Comment: @AaditMShah: "read-only value" is somehow an oxymoron, because all values are read-only (`5=x` won't work either). If you mean "read-only _variable_" this is not correct either, since variables retain their values, while `this` does not.

Comment: @thg435 - Oops, I did indeed mean read-only variable. That being said what does memory retention have anything to do with a variable being read-only or read-write? The `this` pointer does retain its value and its value is a reference (an address) to an object in memory.

Comment: @AaditMShah: With a regular variable, once we assign something to it, this value remains there until we reassign it. The value of `this` changes "by itself" as we enter a new function scope (there's another "variable" with the same property though). That's why tricks like `var me=this` are needed when creating closures with `this`.

Comment: @thg435 - The value of `this` does not change when you enter the scope of a new function. If that were the case then the language would be severely borked. Each function has it's own `this` pointer which [shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing "Variable shadowing - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia") the `this` pointer in its parent functions. The `this` pointer of the parent remains the same (just like any other variable), but is completely inaccessible as it's being shadowed and `this` can't be `delete`d to unshadow it. That's the reason we assign `this` to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something very similar a while back. Unfortunately there's no way to assign a value to `this` - the `this` pointer is a read only variable. However the next best thing is to use a getter and setter object to change the variable holding your instance itself.

Note that this only updates a single reference to the instance. You can read more about it here: [Is there a better way to simulate pointers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10281115/783743)

So this is how it works:

```
function MyClass(pointer, myVar) {
    this.myVar = myVar;

    this.replaceMe = function (value) {
        pointer.value = MyClass.staticHelper(this, pointer, value);
        return pointer.value;
    };

    this.revealVar = function () {
        alert(this.myVar);
    };
}

MyClass.staticHelper = function (instance, pointer, value) {
    return new MyClass(pointer, instance.myVar + value);
};
```

This is how to create the `pointer` and use it:

```
var instance = new MyClass({
    get value() { return instance; },
    set value(newValue) { instance = newValue; }
}, 2);

instance.revealVar();               // alerts 2
instance.replaceMe(40).revealVar(); // alerts 42
```

It's not the most elegant solution but it gets the job done. You can see this code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fpxXL/1/