# Change current object in its prototype

Tags: javascript, prototyping

How to change an object itself, the pointer to object, create another object.

```
Array.prototype.change=function(b){
    // this=b; //does not work
}

a=[1,2,3];
b=[3,2,1];

a.change(b);

console.log(a); // Should be [3,2,1]
```

Another example:

```
String.prototype.double=function(){
    //this+=this; //like str+=str
}

str="hello";

str.double();

console.log(str); // echo "hellohello"
```

Comment: You want to [return the reversed array](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DSeUf/1/), or [return a new variable entirely](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DSeUf/) (as denoted by `b` in your question)? Either way though: `return` whatever (though you may have to pass the 'other' variable in, first. Which makes it a little pointless).

Comment: You can't assign `this`, just `return` something and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: You cannot assign to variables outside of your scope, nor can you assign to `this`. You only can modify the object you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign object to "this"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598549/assign-object-to-this)

Comment: David Thomas, I don't want to return anything. I want to change current object so that a and b were the same object or at least a will be a new object (like this=[])

Comment: Erm... but if you want them to be the same object, what's wrong with `a = b` then? And if you want `a` to become clone of `b`, do [just that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object).

Comment: Yeah. You're adding an unnecessary step. Unless you're trying to do something more complex, the correct answer is a = b.

Comment: I want to do it inside a prototype. I have an academic task. The arrays are just examples.  See another example with string.

Comment: Just assign a newly created object to the same variable like `str = str.double()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your prototype like this:

```
Array.prototype.change = function (b) {
   this.length = 0;
   this.push.apply(this, b);
}
```

Internally it will clear existing data and add data from array in parameter.

This will not make Array a exactly equal Array b (they will still be different objects with different references and `a == b` would be `false`) but data in both will be the same.