# Can I inject a function into a Lua function?

Tags: lua

So if I have this lua function

```
function dostuff(x) 
   function foo () x=x+1; end
   foo(); 
   return x; 
end
```

And it turns out i need foo many times. But it is mainly useful because it has access to the x upvalue. Is there a way to pull foo out of dostuff, but still have it access to x?

I tried to put foo() global and adding it to dostuff, like this:

```
function foo () x=x+1; end
function dostuff(x) 
   foo(); 
   return x; 
end
dostuff.foo = foo
```

Which does not work as in lua functions are distinct from tables (unlike js). 
I still have a feeling that this does work in lua, probably using metatables. But I just not know enough about it yet. I know a lot of ways to avoid this and work around it. I am just curious if there is a way to do it.

Maybe another way to look at is, can you call a global function with a choice of closure?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly it is you're trying to do with this inner function. Who's supposed to access it? Is it just `dostuff`, or are other people talking to it too? Do you really intend to keep *overwriting* the same function every time you call `dostuff`?

Comment: nope, just dostuff. The actual use case is having a lot of dostuff1, dostuff2 etc. functions. And they all (or many of them) end up needing foo. There are fine solutions to this. They can all write foo. I can make foo take x as a parameter.

The first code is what dostuff should do. But if I have many variants of dostuff.. dootherstuff etc. that all want to use foo. Is there a way of the caller of dostuff to have one foo, that acts the same for all of them?

Comment: "*nope, just dostuff. [...] And they all (or many of them) end up needing foo.*" It can't be both. Either they all use the *same* `foo`, or they don't. Which is it? It's not clear what you're actually trying to *accomplish* with this. Can you phrase it in more concrete terms, rather than "foo" and "dostuff"?

Comment: Why don't you pass `foo` as a parameter of `dostuff`? then you can do `dostuff(foo)`

Comment: Well, that's the question. Is there a way to make a foo behave like it is in the dostuff and dostuff2 etc closure without typing it there manually. as i understand it, foo has access to x, because it is running inside dostuff. can i make a foo that can run inside dostuff and dostuff2?

Comment: my specific use case:

Comment: my c api calls lua with a lot of parameters. many different lua implementations of that call. but many of them use the same helper functions. some don't. it would be nice if i could just provide them without change.

Comment: then just pass the function as parameter. Basic high order function. `dostuff(helper)`

Comment: but with dostuff(x,helper).. calling just helper() would it have x in scope? (i just don't know). What if helper was a table of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [dynamic scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping). Unfortunately Lua doesn't have dynamic scoping. It has lexical scoping. In JavaScript you may [simulate dynamic scoping using `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10060857/783743), but Lua doesn't have `eval`.

As a last resort you could use inheritance. The way I usually do inheritance in Lua is using an `extend` function, which is similar to the [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function in JavaScript:

```
local o = {}

function o:extend(table)
    return setmetatable(table, {
        __index = self
    })
end
```

Using this method I can now create an object which will be used for dynamic scoping:

```
local dynamic = o:extend {}

function dynamic:foo()
    self.x = self.x + 1
end
```

The method `foo` is dynamic in the sense that it's variable `x` doesn't point to any specific value. It depends on the value of `self` which can be changed. We use it as follows:

```
function dostuff(x)
    local scope = dynamic:extend {
        x = x
    }

    scope:foo()

    return scope.x
end
```

However instead of creating a new `scope` every time you execute `dostuff` it would be better to simply do:

```
local myscope = dynamic:extend {}

function myscope:dostuff(x)
    self.x = x
    self:foo()
    return self.x
end
```

In fact if you decide to refactor your code as shown above then you don't even need inheritance. All you need to do is:

```
local myscope = {}

function myscope:foo()
    self.x = self.x + 1
end

function myscope:dostuff(x)
    self.x = x
    self:foo()
    return self.x
end
```

The only difference is that now you would have to call `myscope:dostuff` instead of calling `dostuff` directly. This is however a good thing as you don't pollute the global scope.

This is the way I would do it, and this is the way I would recommend that you do it as well. All the Lua standard library functions are also defined on objects.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer was what I was really looking for. :) 

In my context I don't even need objects. Instead of calling dostuff(x) i set a global x, and call dostuff(). Works perfectly fine as the lua instance only ever calls dostuff. I just really wanted to know if lua can do dynamic scoping. Thanks for finding the right name and the simple answer "no".

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner and clearer way would be to just pass arguments to `foo`, which I would recommend.

Another would be to use global variables, or variables local to some chunk (i.e. module or block), common to all related functions.

Otherwise, I didn't find any way to do this. I would suggest redesigning your approach.

Comment: that's what i ended up doing :) i was just curious if i missed some clever trick!

Comment: Good :) The problem with clever tricks is that they're usually too complicated to hold in one's head together with the actual program algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave only a crude example of what you wanted to do and not your actual use case, suggesting an alternative is a bit hard. To start off, to me this is what it sounds like you want

```
local x;
function foo() x=x+1 end
function dostuff(a)
    x = a;
    foo();
    return x;
end
```

My problem here is that `foo` is so simple and there is absolutely no reason to not make it a function that takes a value `x` and returns `x+1`. Further, while the necessary initialisation step for x is not really bad and should not result in any bugs right away, it *will* make development a bit odd when you have to remember to initialize variables for another function and may create a debugging hell if you don't.

So, since Lua also supports multiple return values, the code above is actually a bad idea that gives you no benefit over something like:

```
function foo(a,b,c) return a,b,c end
function dostuff()
    a,b,c = foo(a,b,c);
end
```

Since you wrote about code re-use, here is a general ... *nudge* to what else you can do, which is making use of closures.

You can turn your structure around and make not foo take `x` as an argument, but have `dostuff` take `foo` as an argument:

```
function dostuff(foo)
    return foo()
end
dostuff(function() return 1 end)
dostuff(function() return 2 end)
```

Taking this a step further brings you to a technique called [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

```
function dostuff(foo)
    return function(x)
        return foo(x);
    end
end
dostuff(function(x) return x+1 end)(17)
local f = dostuff(function(x) return x+1 end)
f(17)f(18)f(19) -- ...
```

Now that means you can not only modify the way your function works inside from the outside, but you can *save that state* too. As an added bonus you can also put expensive operations, that you only have to do once per "instance", in the outer function and save some performance.

I hope these are enough ideas to help you with your code re-use issues ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I did not spell out a full use case was that it is easy to solve. :) 
In terms of closures: If I declare a local function inside a function, it has access to the parent function scope. Even if you pass it around. That's the cool part about closures. Now if a closure is only a scope+function, can I make one on my own? 

Call a global function as if it was written local? From other answers I figure no.

Comment: I don't get your 2nd sentence, you did not give us the real code because it would be easier to give an answer? Anyway, of course you can create your own closures. As you already said, functions keep their upvalues, and you can write your own functions. You can't change the upvalues of an existing function but you can always just create a new one. You are probably thinking too Java or C++.