# How to write function-y accepting parameter-fct_x which accesses var-a which is required to be defined in function-y?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
function x() {
    return a + 1; // it can be anything accessing var-a.
}

function y(fct_x) {
    var a = 2;
    fct_x(); // exception: a is not defined
}

y(x);   // exception: see above
        // x is any function which will access var-a which is required to be defined in function-y
```

Question: how to write a function-y like above so that calling fct_x() within function-y will not throw exception?
Note: fct_x is any function (user given) which accesses var-a.  The var-a not defined in function-x, but is required to be defined in function-y.

With referring to [Is it possible to achieve dynamic scoping in JavaScript without resorting to eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060857/is-it-possible-to-achieve-dynamic-scoping-in-javascript-without-resorting-to-eva), I have tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508784/why-eval-a-string-which-defining-a-function-will-get-undefined-instead-of-a-func), but it does not work.

Why I ask above question:
This question comes from "MongoDB mapReduce", like this:
There are 3 properties and 28 functions available for the map-reduction.  One of the 28 function is emit(key,value).  [(See MongoDB doc)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function).

Take this example,

```
function mapFunction() { emit(this.fieldA, this.fieldB) };
db.collection.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {...});  // calling mapReduce-function
```

The emit-function within mapFunction is not defined in mapFunction.  It is "provided"/"defined" somewhere within function db.collection.mapReduce.  How function-db.collection.mapReduce is written to be able to proivde such emit-function for a user-given-mapFunction to call?

[var a] equivalent to [function-emit]
[function y] equivalent to [function-mapReduce]
[function x] equivalent to [function-mapFunction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following answer is inspected by [Is it possible to achieve dynamic scoping in JavaScript without resorting to eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060857/is-it-possible-to-achieve-dynamic-scoping-in-javascript-without-resorting-to-eva)

```
function x() {
    return a + 1; // it can be anything accessing var-a.
}

function y(fct_x) {
    var a = 2;
    var x = eval("(" + String(fct_x) + ")"); // eval(String(fct_x)) will return undefined.
                                             // eval("(" + String(fct_x) + ")") will return a function
    console.log(x()); // 3 
}

y(x);   // exception: see above
        // x is any function which will access var-a which is required to be defined in function-y
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for [dynamic scoping](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DynamicScoping). Javascript is lexically scoped, so to capture a variable, the closure must be textually within its scope. Otherwise, this is not possible, not counting more or less silly tricks like, for example:

```js
function makeClosure(context) {
    return function() {
        return context("a") + 1;
    };
}

function y(evalThis) {
    var a = 2;

    if(evalThis)
        return eval(evalThis);

    return makeClosure(y);
}

closure = y();
document.write(closure()) // 3
```

See also [Is it possible to achieve dynamic scoping in JavaScript without resorting to eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060857/is-it-possible-to-achieve-dynamic-scoping-in-javascript-without-resorting-to-eva) for more discussion and examples.

As to your MongoDB question specifically, it's not possible in pure javascript to inject a variable into some function's scope (again, without resorting to eval). But Mongo's map-reduce is written in C++, not in JS, and can manipulate the scope in arbitrary ways:

```
_scope->setFunction("emit", etc
```

See the [source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/98a7e7f9709413ce06f49b48dee98f7080505947/src/mongo/db/commands/mr.cpp#L857).

For completeness, here's an example with `eval`:

```js
function map(ary, fun) {

    // define some locals
    var LOCAL = 42;

    // re-evaluate the function within the scope
    eval("fun=" + fun);

    // now fun sees our locals
    return ary.map(fun);
}

document.write(
    map([1,2,3], function(x) { return x * LOCAL }) // [ 42, 84, 126 ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, georg.  The answer is close, but not exact due to my question is not clear.  I have edited the question.  Please have a look.

Comment: OK.  MongoDB is written in c++ which can inject scoped function-emit by _scope->setFunction("emit", etc ..  But, can we inject some scoped functions/variables for a user given function to access when calling this function in pure-javascript?  I have the answer now.  See my own answer.  Note: the trick is: within function-y, #1.  define whatever varaibles/functions to be used by function-x.  #2.  Re-create the function-x like this: [ var x = eval("("+String(fct_x)+")"); ].  #3.  run the function-x: [ x(); ].  Now x() accessing those variables/functions defined in function-y.

Comment: @user2899992: glad you figured it out! Note that your code is exactly the same as my second snippet.