# Why does the evaluation of a string defining a function return undefined instead of the function?

Tags: javascript, eval

```
function y(fct) {
   var a = 2;
   var fctStr = String(fct);
   var fct1 = eval(fctStr);
   console.log("fctStr=" + fctStr); // output: fctStr=function x() { return a + 1 }
   console.log("fct1=");
   console.log(fct1);  // output: undefined.  Why it is undefined?  I expect fct1 is a function.
   return fct1();  // exception: undefined is not a function.
}
function x() { return a + 1 }
y(x)   // I expect it returns 3.  However, it throws exception at above "return fct1()" statement.
```

This code in Chrome will get `fct1` as `undefined`.  Why?  I expected that `fct1` would be a function.

Why this question is asked is because of this: [How to write function-y accepting parameter-fct_x which accesses var-a which is required to be defined in function-y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505345/how-to-write-function-y-accepting-parameter-fct-x-which-accesses-var-a-which-is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an expression to be produced.

Change

```
var fct1 = eval(fctStr);
```

to

```
var fct1 = eval("("+fctStr+")");
```

Comment: From the MDN docs: "`eval()` returns the value of the last expression evaluated." - without an expression, there is nothing to return :)

Comment: Your answer is good.  Thank you very much. I have read this, "eval() returns the value of the last expression evaluated.", but it does NOT make me think of I need to do this eval("(" + fctString + ")") instead of eval(fctString).  I must miss something.  What is it?  Or, why var aa = eval("function x() {}") returns undefined?  But var aa = eval("(function x() {})") returns a function?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but I imagine it's the same reason that if you write an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), that you need to wrap it in parenthesis before you can invoke it.

Comment: Yes, read about "statement vs expression", and then "function expression".

Comment: It is an un-document behavior of eval().  I have just added an exmaple to the MDN document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval as "Example: eval a string defining function required "(" and ")" as prefix and suffix"

Comment: It's not un-documented : as pointed by Niet the MDN says you need an expression.

Comment: dystroy, can you show me the link of "statement vs expression"?

Comment: @user2899992: If a function definition such as `function foo() {}` could be parsed as either function *declaration* or function *expression*, it will be parsed as function *declaration*. That happens in your case. A declaration is like a statement. Using the grouping operator (`(...)`) forces the definition to be evaluated as function expression.

Comment: Yes, this is context dependent. You don't need parenthesis when an expression is expected (for example in the list of arguments of a function call or in the right part of an assignment).

Comment: In browser console, input **(function y(){})**, console returns **function y(){}**.  It implies it is a value.  Input **y**, console returns **undefined**.  It means, function-y is not defined yet.  On the other hand, input **function y(){}**, console returns **undefined**, it means it is not a value, implies it is a statement.  Input **y**, console now returns **function y(){}**.  The function-y is declared.

Comment: @JohnsonCheungHK06 Yes. This is also useful to have named function expression not polluting the external scope (mainly for recursive functions).

Answer (score 0):

Other's have answered in bits an pieces, but here's the whole answer:

```
function x() {return a + 1}
```

That defines a function named `x`, this is very similar to the following:

```
var x = function() {return a + 1}
```

In that case, an anonymous function is created and assigned to the variable `x`. So if you want to assign a function to a variable, there shouldn't be an identifier between `function` and `()`.

If you want the `eval` statement to **return** the function, then you need to wrap the function declaration with parenthesis <s>(and **not** give the function a name)</s>. **Edit:** The function name is optional:

```
var x = eval('(function () {return a + 1})');
```

Comment: Hu ? It works when the function expression is named. You can test OP's code with just added parethesis, as per my answer.

Comment: When I first tried it, it didn't work, but I must have fat-fingered something; you are correct, it does work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Is there a document telling people that "function() {}" is a statement-string, but "(function() {})" is expression-string?

Comment: var aa = function() {}; will assign a function to var aa.  This makes people thinking that "function() {}" is an "expression-string".  However, javascript treats it as "statement-string".  We need to use "(function() {})" as "expression-string".