# Achieving dynamic scoping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to execute a function at a different scope than where it is defined. I need to get the variables available in the runtime scope available to the functions context.

A sample code can be like

```
var k = function () { alert(x); };

(function () {

    var x = 100;
    k();

})();
```

Its not possible for function k to access x which is in the scope where it is run.

Possible work arounds that I have are:

1. inject x as a parameter to function
2. use eval like

   ```
   var k = "function () { alert(x); }";

   (function () {

       var x = 100;
       var m = eval("("+k+")");//prints 100
       m();

   })();
   //But this same work around wont work if I use k = "alert(x);" and 
   //define m = new Function(k);
   ```
3. bind x as the `this` context for the function and do `alert(this)`.

If i rule out the above 3 options, are there any other ways of approaching this problem?
Is there a way I can inject variables into a function scope in runtime, just like `call`,`apply` and `bind` does for `this` ?

Comment: No, if you want the variables accessible in the function, you pass them as arguments.

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're really trying to solve since passing `x` as an argument is the obvious solution here?

Comment: @jfriend00 : I am trying to write a library where the user will be able to write functions to decide the flow. Inside the functions he can use some private functions that the library supports. May be like `stop()`,`rework()` etc. Passing them as arguments dint seem good at that point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to achieve dynamic scoping in JavaScript without resorting to eval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060857/is-it-possible-to-achieve-dynamic-scoping-in-javascript-without-resorting-to-eva)

Comment: If you don't want these functions available anywhere else, then pass a single namespace argument to their function (as the first argument) and have all your library functions be properties of that namespace object.  If your functions can be globally accessible, then just put them on a single global namespace object and have the user use them from the global namespace object such as `myLib.stop()` and `myLib.rework()`.  Or make `this` be your namespace object so they can call them as `this.stop()` and `this.rework()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 : I got your point and its solves my problem. But what if I resort to the eval option I mention in the question, just to avoid even injecting the common namespace and just use readily readable functions? Just curious to know what you think of it. And that indeed was the purpose of this question :)

Comment: I tend to avoid `eval()` entirely, but perhaps it has a place in the unique application you have.  I'm not really sure what the pros/cons of using it in that context are.  I'd suggest you read these two references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode to understand things to be aware of when using `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that in your function it's OK to declare a variable and not call `k` directly.

Is `this` suitable for you?

```
var o = 
{
    x : 50,
    k : function() { alert(this.x); }
}

o.k();

(function () {

    this.x = 100;
    var f = o.k;
    f();
    o.k();

})();
```

Comment: nice try. But this is actually doing the 3rd option i mentioned internally.

Comment: But what if I resort to the eval option I mention in the question, just to avoid even using the `this` and just use readily readable functions? Just curious to know what you think of it. And that indeed was the purpose of this question :)